# VS2008: Generate change script for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and MS SQL Server 2005. When I alter a database table in the VS IDE, I have the option to **Generate Change Script...** which creates a change script in my database project. This script can then be ran to keep databases up to date with development.

When I modify a database stored procedure in the VS IDE, I see no similar option. Am I missing something? Is it an acceptable solution to simply copy the **ALTER PROCEDURE** text to a file in the **Change Scripts** directory?

Or should I just use **Generate Create Script...** for stored procedures since they can be created and removed at will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ALTER PROCEDURE statement is perfectly sufficient. See for example [DROP...CREATE vs ALTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644999/drop-create-vs-alter)